# Can't get the range function to work on my list slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

So I need to throttle my pulling so that it will pull 120 csv's a minute
I decided to use a range function where it starts at 0 and steps 120 till the end of my list.Then I am getting a error

> can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
try:
    tickers =['AEGN', 'AMTX', 'AMRK', 'AMWD', 'AMRS', 'AQMS', 'RKDA', 'APWC', 'ATISW', 'BCPC', 'GOLD', 'CLXT', 'CVCO', 'CENX', 'CHNR', 'CDXS', 'BBCP', 'ROAD', 'CRWS', 'CSWI', 'CTIB', 'EVGN', 'GEVO', 'GLDD', 'GPP', 'GPRE', 'GURE', 'HCCI', 'HHT', 'HYGS', 'IOSP', 'FSTR', 'LEGH', 'LMB', 'LOOP', 'MBII', 'MTRX', 'MERC', 'MEOH', 'MPVD', 'MYRG', 'NEWA', 'NWPX', 'ZEUS', 'OPNT', 'OCC', 'OSN', 'PEIX', 'PAAS', 'PATK', 'PESI', 'PLPC', 'PRIM', 'REGI', 'RGLD', 'SIC', 'SNES', 'SMED', 'SND', 'SSRM', 'STLD', 'SRCL', 'STRL', 'SYNL', 'SES', 'TANH', 'USLM', 'UFPI', 'USAP', 'MYT', 'WDFC', 'WWR', 'YTEN', 'AXU', 'ALO', 'AAU', 'USAS', 'AKG', 'AUG', 'ASM', 'BTG', 'BIOX', 'CMCL', 'LEU', 'LODE', 'DNN', 'EMX', 'UUUU', 'EGI', 'FSI', 'GMO', 'GORO', 'GSV', 'AUMN', 'GSS', 'GV', 'GPL', 'SIM', 'THM', 'MAG', 'MMX', 'NGD', 'NXE', 'NAK', 'NG', 'NRCG', 'PZG', 'PLG', 'PLM', 'SAND', 'SMTS', 'SVM', 'SILV', 'XPL', 'TRX', 'TGB', 'TMQ', 'URG', 'UEC', 'VGZ', 'WRN', 'ASIX', 'AEM', 'APD', 'AKS', 'AGI', 'AIN', 'ALB', 'AA', 'ATI', 'ACH', 'AMRC', 'AVD', 'AU', 'MT', 'AGX', 'AXTA', 'BDC', 'BHP', 'BBU', 'BVN', 'CBT', 'CCJ', 'CSL', 'CRS', 'CE', 'CF', 'CHRA', 'CC', 'CGA', 'CHD', 'CINR', 'CLH', 'CLW', 'CLF', 'CDE', 'CMC', 'CMP', 'CSTM', 'GLW', 'CVA', 'CVIA', 'CULP', 'UAN', 'UFS', 'DOW', 'DRD', 'DD', 'DY', 'EMN', 'ECL', 'EGO', 'ESI', 'EXK', 'NPO', 'EVA', 'FOE', 'AG', 'FTK', 'FLR', 'FMC', 'FSM', 'FBHS', 'FNV', 'FCX', 'FF', 'GCP', 'GLT', 'GFI', 'GRAM', 'GVA', 'FUL', 'HMY', 'HL^B', 'HXL', 'HCR', 'HBM', 'HUN', 'IAG', 'NGVT', 'IBP', 'IFFT', 'IP', 'IPI', 'ICL', 'JEC', 'JELD', 'KBR', 'KGC', 'KL', 'KOP', 'KRA', 'KRO', 'LEN.B', 'LIN', 'LAC', 'LTHM', 'LPX', 'LXU', 'LXFR', 'LYB', 'MLM', 'MAS', 'DOOR', 'MTZ', 'MUX', 'MDU', 'MTL', 'MSB', 'MTX', 'MOS', 'NP', 'NEU', 'NEM', 'NEXA', 'NL', 'OSB', 'NUE', 'NTR', 'OLN', 'OMN', 'OEC', 'ORN', 'OR', 'POL', 'PKX', 'PPG', 'PQG', 'PVG', 'PG', 'KWR', 'RYAM', 'RS', 'RFP', 'REX', 'RIO', 'ROG', 'RPM', 'RYI', 'SWM', 'SMG', 'SA', 'SEE', 'SXT', 'SBGL', 'SHI', 'SKY', 'SQM', 'SCCO', 'SCL', 'SUM', 'SXC', 'SUZ', 'TECK', 'TS', 'TX', 'AES', 'TMST', 'TWI', 'BLD', 'TREX', 'TSE', 'TROX', 'TRQ', 'TPC', 'SLCA', 'UN', 'UL', 'X', 'VALE', 'VHI', 'VVV', 'VNTR', 'VRS', 'VSM', 'VMC', 'GRA', 'WST', 'WLK', 'WLKP', 'WPM', 'XIN', 'AUY']
    start = 0
    endRange = range(0 , len(tickers), 120)
    for end in endRange:
        for ticker in tickers[start:end]:
            apikey = '5GHO8XJWL6V9N27MO'
            str(apikey)
            print(ticker)
        start = end + start + 1
        time.sleep(60)
        print('*************\n' + start + '\n*************')
        print('*************\n' + end + '\n*************')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I am expecting printing out 120 stocks with ""Already have" + ticker" if it has it already then:

```
0
119
```

sleep for 60 seconds
then the next 120 stocks then:

```
120
239
```

and so on until "tickers" is loaded

Comment: *Where* in your code does the error occur?  When you run it with a debugger, what is the first point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: The error "range built-in referenced when not iterating" happens on:                             endRange = range(0 , len(tickers), 120)                                                                       I am not sure when the other error happens

Comment: @DavidLong that is not an error, that is a very misguided pylint warning. Which goes to show, don't always trust your linter...

Comment: Ok but I still get the "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" error when I run my script @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DavidLong you need to look at the links that have been provided in the comments about how to provide a [mcve]. At the very least, you could post the full error message including the stack trace, which will tell use **exactly** where the error is occurring. You need to help us help you. Dumping context free code (wrapped in a bare try-except!) is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are the problem.

print('*************\n' + start + '\n*************')
print('*************\n' + end + '\n*************')

Since, start and end are numbers python throws that it cannot concatenate string and Integer error. Try formatting the string or by making the variables start and end to string at the time of printing.

Comment: That was it changed it to:                                                                                                        
     print("*******************\n + str(start) _ '\n*********************")                                             
     print("*******************\n + str(end) _ '\n*********************")                                                and it worked Thank you so much @Yogaraj !